# How to set XML string after concat'ing in Java?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, concatenation

So I've followed the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) to concatenate XML string values with other things, and as a result have the following code:

```
//XML strings.xml
<string name="start_next_act_string">The next activity has been scheduled to automatically launch in %1$d seconds!</string>

//layout/activity_home.XML
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/start_next_act_string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

//Home.java inside class, but outside oncreate
int startNextActivityInSeconds = 10;

//Home.java inside class and inside oncreate
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Resources res = getResources();
        String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.start_next_act_string), startNextActivityInSeconds);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

However on the Android screen it prints out

> The next activity has been scheduled to automatically launch in %1$d seconds!

rather than

> The next activity has been scheduled to automatically launch in 10 seconds!

How do I update XML string such that it displays the concat'd string result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that what you're trying to do doesn't work. When the layout is inflated, the string is used exactly as defined in the resource file.

For this, you have to set the text explicitly, i.e.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.theId);
tv.setText(text);
```

where "theId" is the id you have to set for the TextView in the xml file, for example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/theId"
    android:text="@string/start_next_act_string"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `TextView`'s text property to the new String you've created, otherwise the formatted string will be solely stored in your local String and won't reflected in the UI.

First you need to name your TextView by giving it an ID:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/YourId"
    ...
```

Afterwards, bind to the view from your `Activity` and actively modify its text:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.YourId);
myTextView.setText(text);
```